# PSEXEC Crashing PC

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I have been using psexec successfully for a couple of years now. Recently, I have had some major issues when running on several remote machines. Calling psexec from a simple batch file seems to completely crash (restart) the computer, leaving the bewildered pc locked on the DELL startup screen (same issue on 3 separate computers).

Anyone having a similar issue? This seems to occur when using the old and new version of psexec (May 2014 release v2.11). Could this be a windows update issue (Windows 7 64bit)?

FYI, here's the process I call from a .bat file (run_model.cmd contains local exe).. note: This opens up in a loop, so that I get a new window for each model run.

```
start cmd.exe /c psexec -i -s \\VOSTRO460-4 \\VOSTRO460-4\model\run_model.cmd
```

If not, can anyone suggest an alternative to psexec which works as simply as this?

Cheers

Neil

Comment: This question is better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) since it isn't about programming.

Comment: Nope - definately a psexec issue. I've tried with PAExec and she works like a dream.. Strange.

Comment: The plot thickens. PAExec crashed on one of the machines I'm running. I'm starting to think the issue is a 64bit program I'm calling in the batch file. My understanding is that PSExec is a 32 bit image, and therefore can have some issues with 64bit applications...

Comment: we have moved from `ps tools` to `winRM` and it is good and stable alternative